# eval parse character into function call r

Tags: r, eval, radix

I have an externally specified object with class character:

```
X = "c(Arg1 = 'First', Arg2 = 'Second', Arg3 = 'Third')"
```

that I want to directly plug into a function in R simply as **foo(X)**

The following is an example of what I want done:

```
Inputs <- eval(parse(text = X))

Msg_Foo <- function(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3) {
    message(paste(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, sep = "\n"))
 }

Msg_Foo(
    Arg1 = Inputs["Arg1"], 
    Arg2 = Inputs["Arg2"],
    Arg3 = Inputs["Arg3"]
    )
```

But ideally I want a solution that simply requires:

```
Msg_Foo(Inputs)
```

This is important as I want to specify an ellipse (...) in the function, so that arguments from X is directly passed through to function without explicit specification as in the example above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's generally not a good idea to eval/parse strings in R unless you are 100% sure they are safe.

But you can dynamically pass arguments to functions with `do.call()`. For example

```
# X = "c(Arg1 = 'First', Arg2 = 'Second', Arg3 = 'Third')"
# Inputs <- eval(parse(text = X))

Msg_Foo <- function(x) {
  message(do.call("paste", c(as.list(x), sep="\n")))
}    
Msg_Foo(Inputs)
```

Your inputs are a named character vector. We need to turn that into a named list to use with `do.call` and then can pass those to the paste function. Then we just pass the result to the `message()` function as normal

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, I am aware of do.calls, but that only solves the specific pasting exercise used as illustration (and not of much use). I am more interested in a general means of passing the named vectors into the function arguments. The last part of my question mentions possible use of an ellipse - requiring a form of eval parse (I assume they are safe). Ideas?

Comment: @Nick just cast the named vector to a list and use `do.call`. This isn't at all specific to `paste()`. If you wanted something else I can't tell from your example.

Comment: I effectively want Msg_Foo(Inputs) to be the exact equivalent of typing out Msg_Foo(Arg1 = 'First', Arg2 = 'Second', Arg3 = 'Third'), where Inputs <- "c(Arg1 = 'First', Arg2 = 'Second', Arg3 = 'Third')". Not sure how do.call would do that?

Comment: But you don’t want to change the body of Msg_Foo? You want it to accept both versions? Because that’s not generally how function calls work. You could test what’s passed to the first parameter of the function to see if it’s a named vector I guess. But otherwise you would just do `do.call(“Msg_Foo”, as.list(Inputs))`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick - you were spot on with that. The general solution I was looking for is: do.call("Msg_Foo", as.list(eval(parse(text = X)))).